# Parse a stream of space separated numbers

Tags: c#, performance, .net, parsing, integer

I need to parse a *stream* of characters `IEnumerable<char>` as a list of space (and newline) separated numbers.

Numbers can be expressed in base 10, base 8 (with `0` prefix) and base 16 (with `0x` prefix). They can be both positive and negative (also for hex numbers then, for example, `-0xff` is a valid input), leading sign is optional.

`FormatException` should be thrown for invalid numbers and `OverflowException` should be thrown for out of `Int32` range numbers. Parsing does not need to support thousands separator and input characters are always in the ASCII range.

Parsing has to be as fast as possible but without sacrificing readability too much.

Implementation (few more *helper* methods are omitted) is:

```
public sealed class Int32Parser
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> Parse(string text)
        => new Int32Parser().Consume(text);

    public IEnumerable<int> Consume(IEnumerable<char> stream)
    {
        if (stream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));

        _stream = stream.GetEnumerator();

        _hasMoreCharactersToConsume = TryMoveToNextCharacter();
        while (_hasMoreCharactersToConsume)
        {
            if (ParseNextNumber(out int number))
                yield return number;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator<char> _stream;
    private bool _hasMoreCharactersToConsume;

    private char CurrentCharacter => _stream.Current;

    private bool ParseNextNumber(out int number)
    {
        number = 0;

        if (!SkipLeadingWhiteSpaces())
            return false;

        int sign = ParseOptionalSign();
        int numericBase = ParseOptionalBasePrefix();

        while (!IsWhiteSpaceOrNewLine(CurrentCharacter))
        {
            int digit = ParseDigit(CurrentCharacter);
            if (digit >= numericBase)
                throw new FormatException($"Invalid digit {digit} for base {numericBase}.");

            checked
            {
                number = (number * numericBase) + digit;
            }

            if (!TryMoveToNextCharacter())
                break;
        }

        number = sign * number;

        return true;
    }

    private bool SkipLeadingWhiteSpaces()
    {
        while (IsWhiteSpaceOrNewLine(CurrentCharacter))
        {
            if (!TryMoveToNextCharacter())
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private int ParseOptionalSign()
    {
        if (CurrentCharacter == '-')
        {
            MoveToNextCharacter();
            return -1;
        }

        if (CurrentCharacter == '+')
            MoveToNextCharacter();

        return 1;
    }

    private int ParseOptionalBasePrefix()
    {
        if (CurrentCharacter != '0')
            return 10;

        if (!TryMoveToNextCharacter())
            return 10;

        if (CurrentCharacter != 'x' && CurrentCharacter != 'X')
            return 8;

        MoveToNextCharacter();

        return 16;
    }

    private int ParseDigit(char c)
    {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            return c - '0';

        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
            return c - 'A' + 10;

        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
            return c - 'a' + 10;

        throw new FormatException($"Unknown digit {c}");
    }

    private static bool IsWhiteSpaceOrNewLine(char c)
        => c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\r';

    private bool TryMoveToNextCharacter()
        => _hasMoreCharactersToConsume = _stream.MoveNext();

    private void MoveToNextCharacter()
    {
        if (!TryMoveToNextCharacter())
            throw new FormatException("Expected more characters.");
    }
}
```

A simple test:

```
foreach (var number in Int32Parser.Parse("  2147483647 -1 -2 3 0xa  0xb 010 0 0x \n+1 +100 -33   \n"))
    Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Direct performance comparison isn't fair (for `Int32.Parse()`) because requirements are pretty different (and the test measures also *quality* of my own implementation together with `String.Split()`) but here a small quick-and-dirty performance comparison:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (int numberOfDigits in Enumerable.Range(1, 9))
            Compare(numberOfDigits);
    }

    private static void Compare(int numberOfDigits)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Numbers with {0} digits", numberOfDigits);

        var testString = CreateTestString(numberOfDigits);

        Console.WriteLine(" Testing native 1");
        Console.WriteLine("  Total elapsed time: {0} ticks", Measure(testString, ParseNetNative1));

        Console.WriteLine(" Testing native 2");
        Console.WriteLine("  Total elapsed time: {0} ticks", Measure(testString, ParseNetNative2));

        Console.WriteLine(" Testing custom");
        Console.WriteLine("  Total elapsed time: {0} ticks", Measure(testString, ParseCustom));
    }

    private static string CreateTestString(int numberOfDigits)
    {
        int minValue = (int)Math.Pow(10, numberOfDigits) / 10;
        int maxValue = (int)Math.Pow(10, numberOfDigits + 1) - 1;

        var rnd = new Random();

        return String.Join(" ", GenerateRandomNumbers()) + "\n" + String.Join("  ", GenerateRandomNumbers());

        IEnumerable<int> GenerateRandomNumbers()
            => Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(x => rnd.Next(minValue, minValue) * ((rnd.Next() & 1) == 1 ? 1 : -1));
    }

    private static long Measure(string text, Func<string, int> method)
    {
        const int repetitions = 1000;

        int result = method(text);

        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        for (int i=0; i < repetitions; ++i)
            result = method(text);

        stopwatch.Stop();

        return stopwatch.ElapsedTicks / repetitions;
    }

    private static int ParseNetNative1(string text)
    {
        return text.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(x => Int32.Parse(x, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            .Count();
    }

    private static int ParseNetNative2(string text)
    {
        var numbersToParse = text.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var numbers = new int[numbersToParse.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
            numbers[i] = Int32.Parse(numbersToParse[i], NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        return numbers.Length;
    }

    private static int ParseCustom(string text)
    {
        return Int32Parser.Parse(text).Count();
    }
}
```

`Int32.Parse()` does not support negative hex numbers then they're excluded from this comparison but I suppose a similar figure. A quick plot follows; numbers are in ticks for a long string made of 20k numbers with N digit, roughly 50% of them are negative, first 10k separated with one space then one new line and then another 10 k separated with two spaces (see `CreateTestString()`):

[image: Performance comparison chart]

Parsing a string (without hex negative numbers) is not the only use-case but it's an important one, if `TestNative1()` or `TestNative2()` are obviously inefficient then I'm open to critiques also about them. Here a *reference* implementation as used in tests:

```
private const char[] Separators = new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r' };

private static IEnumerable<int> ParseNetNative1(string text)
{
    return text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(x => Int32.Parse(x, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}

private static IEnumerable<int> ParseNetNative2(string text)
{
    var numbersToParse = text.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var numbers = new int[numbersToParse.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
        numbers[i] = Int32.Parse(numbersToParse[i], NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing GenerateRandomNumbers method for me to run your code.

Comment: @CharlesNRice it's a _local function_ of `CreateTestString()`. It's a C# 7 thing, if you're using a previous version you need to move it outside and to refactor the _out variable_ in `Int32Parser.Consume()`

Comment: Since `number = (number * numericBase) + digit;` is running in a `checked` block, it will fail for numbers that are too big in absolute values (about `int.MaxValue/10` or `int.MinValue/10`). I hope your input will not have values like that.

Comment: Yes, it's checked to throw OverflowException for big numbers (outside Int32 range) but parsing one digit from left to right it works smoothly for the others (it's the first test in the small snippet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm seems to be fine and all members have nice and clear names so the code documents itself pretty well. However as a whole I don't like implementation. I find that the parser is a little bit messy and chaotic. I especially don't like these two fields that are modified *all over the place* by various methods and make the parser thread-unsafe.

> ```
> private IEnumerator<char> _stream;
> private bool _hasMoreCharactersToConsume;
> ```

If I had one instance of the parser and called `Consume` in two different threads weird things would happen. You try to hide it by instantiating it via the `static` method `Parse` but the default constructor isn't private so theoretically it's possible to use it incorrectly.

---

I suggest the following changes:

- It would be better to have only one instance method `Parse` and make the other ones static and pass the `IEnumerator<char>` and other required parameters to them so that they can advance it themselfes if necessary and be almost *pure* methods with the exception of advancing the enumerator.
- It would be cleaner to call all methods `TrySomething` and consequently return a `bool` and the result via an `out` parameter because each of them can reach the end.
- An enumerator is disposable so a `using` should be added.
- I like the new `switch` with filters so I think it would be cleaner to use it nearly everywhere here.
- If you want to add an index to the error message where the invalid charachter was found I would create a custom enumerator that provides an additional property like `CurrentIndex` that could be implemented as a private class of the parser.

Example:

```
public class Int32Parser
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Parse(string text)
    {
        using (var enumerator = text.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                if (IsWhiteSpaceCharacter(enumerator.Current))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (TryReadNumber(enumerator, out var number))
                {
                    yield return number;
                }
                else
                {
                    yield break;
                }               
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool TryReadNumber(IEnumerator<char> enumerator, out int number)
    {
        number = 0;

        if (!TryReadSign(enumerator, out var sign)) return false;
        if (!TryReadBasePrefix(enumerator, out var basePrefix)) return false;

        while (TryReadDigit(enumerator, out var digit))
        {
            checked
            {
                number = (number * basePrefix) + digit;
            }

            if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) return false;
        }

        number = sign * number;
        return true;
    }

    private static bool TryReadSign(IEnumerator<char> enumerator, out int sign)
    {
        switch (enumerator.Current)
        {
            case '-':
                sign = -1;
                return enumerator.MoveNext();

            case '+':
                sign = 1;
                return enumerator.MoveNext();

            default:
                sign = 1; // assume its' positive
                return true;
        }
    }

    private static bool TryReadBasePrefix(IEnumerator<char> enumerator, out int basePrefix)
    {
        basePrefix = -1;

        switch (enumerator.Current)
        {
            case '0':
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) return false;
                switch (enumerator.Current)
                {
                    case 'X':
                    case 'x':
                        basePrefix = 16;
                        return enumerator.MoveNext();
                    case char c when '0' <= c && c <= '7':
                        basePrefix = 8;
                        return true; // don't move, it's a digit
                    default:
                        basePrefix = 10; // assume it's decimal
                        return true; // don't move, it's a digit
                }
            default:
                basePrefix = 10; // assume it's decimal
                return true; // don't move, it's a digit
        }
    }

    private static bool TryReadDigit(IEnumerator<char> enumerator, out int digit)
    {
        switch (enumerator.Current)
        {
            case char c when (c >= '0' && c <= '9'):
                digit = c - '0';
                return true;

            case char c when (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F'):
                digit = c - 'A' + 10;
                return true;

            case char c when (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f'):
                digit = c - 'a' + 10;
                return true;

            // we're done reading digits
            case char c when IsWhiteSpaceCharacter(enumerator.Current):
                digit = -1;
                return false;

            default:
                throw new FormatException($"Unknown character '{enumerator.Current}'.");
        }
    }

    private static bool IsWhiteSpaceCharacter(char c)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case ' ':
            case '\t':
            case '\r':
            case '\n':
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In my tests it was slightly faster then then original implementation although I'm not sure where the performance improvement actually comes from.

Comment: The slight performance gain is probably happening because everything is a static method. I find your switch statements more readable; but I'm not a big fan of `continue` in any code unless there is just no other way.

Comment: @Svek right, an `else` would be better here. I'll fix that later as I'm not a big fan of `continue`s either.

Comment: I'm not fully convinced about the `enumerator` parameter, I have a `class` then I'm usually happy to use instance fields to share variables 
 [exactly because] used by all methods. About everything else...I love this implementation, it's much more easy to understand and to follow. Especially `TryXyz()` made code MUCH better than my original one (those `MoveToNextCharacter()` + `TryMoveToNextCharacter()` thrown all around really bothered me...)

Answer (score 1):

You will *not* like my answer. **TL;DR:** I could not find a specific point where a code change would lead to performance improvement. I have, however, noticed some correctness issues.

---

## Get "Enough" Test Samples

Below is the **"test bench"** I used to compile your solution before feeding it to a profiler. If you uncomment the console output instruction in the `catch` block, you'll be able to see some unhandled exception which could be caused by either bad input my code generated or a bug in the parser code.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var errCount = 0;
        foreach (var line in Generate())
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var number in Int32Parser.Parse(line))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(line + " ----> " + number);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                errCount++;
                //Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }

        //Console.WriteLine(errCount);
    }

    static Random rnd = new Random(0);

    private static IEnumerable<string> Generate(int totalCount = 1024)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        for (var counter = 1; counter <= totalCount; counter++)
        {
            var items = GenerateItems();
            result.Add(
                string.Join(" ", items)
            );
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GenerateItems(int totalItemCount = 1024)
    {
        var items = new List<string> { };
        for (var counter = 1; counter <= totalItemCount; counter++)
            items.Add(Generators[rnd.Next(0, Generators.Length)]());
        return items.OrderBy(_ => rnd.Next(0, items.Count));
    }

    static int MaxValue = int.MaxValue / 11;
    static int MinValue = int.MinValue / 11;
    static Func<string>[] Generators = new Func<string>[]
    {
        () => rnd.Next(0, MaxValue).ToString(),
        () => "+" + rnd.Next(0, MaxValue).ToString(),
        () => rnd.Next(MinValue, -1).ToString(),
        () => 0.ToString(),
        () => "0x" + rnd.Next(0, int.MaxValue / 11).ToString("x"),
        () => "0" + Convert.ToString(rnd.Next(0, MaxValue), 8),
        () => "\n",
        () => "\t",
        () => "\r",
        () => " ",
    };

}
```

---

## Performance Improvement should be Data Driven

After running profiler, I got a **chart** to work with. Mapping the invocation stats to the instructions in the source code did not give me many ideas. What's worse, the few ideas which popped out, are pretty crazy.

Please notice that this is generated by compiling into .NET Core dll. The .NET FW Classic results may be different.

[image: performance-diagram]

I may be very wrong, but maybe, just maybe, materializing the `IEnumerable<char>` into a `char[]` and dealing with current and possible next character via indices is a faster solution. I really doubt that using the string's `IEnumerator<char>::Current` or `IEnumerator<char>::MoveNext()` is slow, but what if it is? With char array we know for sure that element-by-index access costs \$O(1)\$. Same is true with reach-line-end check -- \$O(1)\$ if implemented based on a known current index and total string length.

If your real code works with a `string`, I don't see how `char[]` would be a bad thing to do *if it improves the performance*. However, if the code is indeed a template for working with real `char`-producing streams/IEnumerables, it may lead to memory consumption problems.

### Not an answer, really

The reason, I think this "optimization" will *not* work, is because we're talking about `string` and `IEnumerable<T>`. I don't believe we can possibly beat the implementation(s) of these fundamental pieces of .NET platform.

## P.S.

As mentioned, the code looks pretty good to me. No obvious flaws are seen. But this is a highly algorithmic code in nature so to speak. Only an excessive set of unit- and integration tests will help getting more confidence with *correctness* of the solution. I'll just assume that the tests are in place and all green.

Hopefully, other reviewers will be able to provide more valuable feedback.

Comment: It's not a bad idea, here I was trying to fit few different use cases (input as `string`, `StringBuilder` and `IEnumerable<char>` from a blocking network stream) then I went with the _maximum common divisor_ `IEnumerable<char>` but to squeeze better performance (I still need to measure in a real world usage scenario) I might have to go with specialized versions (unfortunately `string` and `StringBuilder` don't share any interface with indexer access)

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially benchmarking against `Int.Parse()` --- which tends to have slower performance than hand-coded versions for specific purposes.

Here is an example that shows you that

```
private static _delimters = new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r' };

// this method is exactly the same as your ParseNetNative2() method
// except we are NOT using the Int32.Parse, instead we use the alternative one
private static int ParseCustom2(string text)
{
    var numbersToParse = text.Split(_delimters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    var numbers = new int[numbersToParse.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; ++i)
        numbers[i] = CustomInt32Parse(numbersToParse[i]); // <-- not using Int32.Parse

    return numbers.Length;
}

//alternative method to Int32.Parse
//credit: http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int  
private static int CustomInt32Parse(string s)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        result = result * 10 + (s[i] - '0');

    return result;
}
```

With this approach I was getting generally better results than your current implementation.

```
// custom = Your ParseCustom() method
// custom 2 = My ParseCustom2() method **above**

Numbers with 1 digits
  Testing custom   || Total elapsed time: 3791 ticks
  Testing custom 2 || Total elapsed time: 3611 ticks //<-- better
Numbers with 2 digits
  Testing custom   || Total elapsed time: 4455 ticks
  Testing custom 2 || Total elapsed time: 3792 ticks //<-- better (always)
Numbers with 3 digits
  Testing custom   || Total elapsed time: 5258 ticks
  Testing custom 2 || Total elapsed time: 4235 ticks //<-- better
Numbers with 4 digits
  Testing custom   || Total elapsed time: 6191 ticks
  Testing custom 2 || Total elapsed time: 6549 ticks //<-- ?
Numbers with 5 digits
  Testing custom   || Total elapsed time: 6927 ticks
  Testing custom 2 || Total elapsed time: 4762 ticks //<-- better (always)
Numbers with 6 digits
  Testing custom   || Total elapsed time: 7725 ticks
  Testing custom 2 || Total elapsed time: 7689 ticks //<-- better
Numbers with 7 digits
  Testing custom   || Total elapsed time: 8660 ticks
  Testing custom 2 || Total elapsed time: 6062 ticks //<-- better (always)
Numbers with 8 digits
  Testing custom   || Total elapsed time: 10111 ticks
  Testing custom 2 || Total elapsed time: 8362 ticks //<-- better (always)
Numbers with 9 digits
  Testing custom   || Total elapsed time: 11399 ticks
  Testing custom 2 || Total elapsed time: 8615 ticks //<-- better (always)
```

I think the only merit with my suggested solution is easier readability in terms of code to maintain. It has consistently beat your approach especially with 2, 5, 7, 8 and 9 digits.

> However, according to the author of the above alternative to the
>   `Int32.Parse()` there are some constraints to be aware of...
>
> The alternative method assumes all numbers:
>
> - are positive
> - do not have thousandths separators or decimal points
> - contain no scientific or other special notations
> - and all conversions will happen with no exception testing because I’m just wanting to test the raw speed of converting.

Something very unusual, but your algorithm seems to always outperform mine, when dealing with 4 digits?